# Есть ли разница между понятиями "гололёд" и "гололедица"?

Tags: лингвистика

Есть ли разница между понятиями "гололед" и "гололедица" или это синонимы?

Comment: Судя по формулировкам - одно и то же

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Гололед и гололедица -  совершенно разные понятия. Первое - явление природы, второе - ее состояние.

Гололедица - это лед на поверхности, который появляется при понижении температуры в результате замерзания воды образовавшейся при таянии снега и льда во время оттепели. При колебаниях температуры около нуля гололедица бывает довольно часто.

Гололед - это образование льда на земле, деревьях, проводах и пр., связанное с замерзанием дождя, выпадающего на холодную поверхность. Чаще всего гололед возникает при резком потеплении из изморози, когда теплый воздух проходит над сильно охлажденной поверхностью.  Это значительно более редкое и опасное явление, особенно для энергетиков и автомобилистов, так как трудно предсказывается, обычно быстро и интенсивно развивается.
В прогнозе погоды мы слышим: "гoлoлед, на дopoгах гoлoледица".